# What is the proper way to address the Emperor in person？

Tags: meaning, words

Is there a proper way to address the Emperor of Japan when meeting in person? Is he addressed as 天皇 or 天皇陛下?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He is addressed as [陛下]{へいか} ("Your Majesty"). Directly calling him [天皇]{てんのう} would be rude. Princes and princesses are addressed as [殿下]{でんか} ("Your Highness").